# Visual Studio 2015 - Debug require additional compilation

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I just upgrade from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015, and I noticed a difference which really bothering me:

We have a big solution, we usually do "Rebuild all" operation, then when we edit a file, we just rebuild the library that we just did modify, then we start in debug the client.

This was working very nicely in VS2013, but now, with VS2015, even if I do:

1. Rebuild all
2. Directly after, right click, Debug

It tries to rebuild some of the DLL. Worse, if I need two instances, I do the rebuild all, Debug once, and a second debug, it tries to compile a second time(which fails because the DLL are in use by the first debug.

In our case, we have multiple clients interacting with each others, so we often start in debug one, then start in debug the other. But they have some project in common, which the second debug client tries to rebuild.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior??? This is totally new for us in VS2015.

Comment: You'll have to dig through the detailed build trace to see why it decides to compile again.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity setting.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you i didn't know that. I got this :

"1>Project 'XXX' is not up to date. CopyLocal reference source 'E:\Dev\WS1\Trunk\Lib\DevExpress\DevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core.dll' is more recent than 'E:\Dev\WS1\Trunk\Debug\x86\DevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core.dll'."

But DevExpress is not something we update, so why would it be considered as newer?

Comment: Are these two copies of dll the same? Why do they have different timestamp? Someone is copying that dll to your Debug\x86 folder; I would find out - where from?

Comment: @VladFeinstein They have the same size, same modified date, same assembly version, so I think it's safe to say they are safe. This dll is the reference of several of our projects, they all copy it from the same source.

Comment: Are you saying that the statement `A is more recent than B` is false in this case? You've mentioned `modified` date, but what about `created` and `accessed`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein The modified date is the same. The Created and Accessed date are different(those two date seems to be changed every time I build, no idea why????)This file is even in readonly, it's a DLL provided by DevExpress, we don't even have the hability(nor the wish) to edit it.

Comment: See if this helps (I am reading it as we speak, too): http://ofekshilon.com/2015/08/16/visual-studio-projects-that-just-keep-rebuilding-or-how-quantum-mechanics-mess-up-your-build/